# How to display json key in structured streaming in spark through scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, streaming

I am new to spark and trying to understand structured streaming ,I want to display json key from kafka to spark console any help would be of great help.

Spark code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.ProcessingTime

object kafka_stream {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("kafka-consumer")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

//    val schema = StructType().add("a", IntegerType()).add("b", StringType())

    val schema = StructType(Seq(
      StructField("a", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("b", StringType, true)
    ))

    val df = spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "172.21.0.187:9093")
    .option("subscribe", "test")
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
    .load()


    values = df.select("a.*")

    values.writeStream
      .outputMode("complete")
      .format("console")
      .start()a
      .awaitTermination()
```

I want to display extract entire json and display it to the spark console

My input to kafka

```
{
    "a": {
       "b": 1,
       "c": 2
    }
}
```

Output to spark console should be something like this

```
 {
   "a": {
          "b": 1,
          "c": 2
       }
  }
```

Comment: it's the same thing ? or I'm not seeing something :)

Comment: I am not able to get you,can you please elaborate it @dumitru

Comment: use values.show in your code after values = df.select("a.*")